# Looping a List of ggplot Objects into a Modal Window

Tags: r, shinydashboard

In my shinydashboard, I would like my modal window to display 49 ggplots, which are all stored in the list temp1. I can get the modal window to display any of the plots like so:

```
observeEvent(input$modalTrigger1,
  {
    temp1 <- plotList(data)
     showModal(modalDialog(plotOutput("trigger1plot1")))

     output$trigger1plot1 <- renderPlot(temp1[[1]])
  }
  )
```

But I want to create a for loop that would output all 49 plots in the modal window when modalTrigger1 (an action button) is pressed. My attempts thus far to do so have failed, so I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want 49 plots in one modal window? Or 49 separate modal windows? Both seem excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `gridExtra::grid.arrange` to combine multiple plots where you can even specify *nrow* and *ncol*. See [CRAN-R docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf).

```
library(gridExtra)
...

observeEvent(input$modalTrigger1,
{
  temp1 <- plotList(data)
  showModal(modalDialog(plotOutput("trigger1plot1")))

  output$trigger1plot1 <- renderPlot({
      do.call(grid.arrange, temp1
      # grid.arrange(grobs = temp1)  -- ALTERNATIVE W/ gridExtra v>=2.0.0

      # do.call(grid.arrange, c(temp1, ncol=7, nrow=7))  -- WITH ROWS/COLS
  })

})
```